# windows batch command to detect ip address from hosts file

Tags: windows, batch-file, ip, localhost, host

can any one, help me to detect any statements which are not having #, ie. non commented statements from hosts file (/system32/drivers/etc/hosts) using windows batch commands ?

For example  : ip address specified in that file which will not have #

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me:

```
findstr "^[^#]*[0-9a-f][.:][0-9a-f]" c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts
```

Comment: This fails for IPV6 addresses

Comment: Incorrectly detects `   # 1.10 does nothing` (it has spaces before the hash)

Comment: @MCND good call. I was thinking only about # in first position. I think im good now. Findstr regex is pretty lame huh

Comment: Sorry, it fails in ipv6 addresses in the form ::ffff:222.1.40.40

Comment: @MCND are you sure? It should match on the third colon of your example, shouldn't it? Ie the part after `[^#]*` should match `f:2`, right?

Comment: You are right, sorry. Luckily I slept and could not make more mistakes. Back again. What about `::1`?

Answer (score 1):

This will find non-commented lines

```
find /v "#" < hosts
```

Comment: Fails not detecting `10.0.0.0 somewhere # this is informational`

Comment: @MCND Yeah, that line has a comment on it. :D  I was aware of that but the question just asks for non commented lines.

Answer (score 1):

Not completly sure this does not leave something without filtering. But

```
findstr /R /c:"^[^#]*[0-9a-f:.]" %systemroot%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts
```

It will incorrectly? detect lines that contains invalid formated ip address resolutions (ej: an ip address and no name) But should remove any commented/not active lines.

Answer (score 1):

This code just show lines that don't have a # in first column, hope this helps:

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /f "delims=¶ tokens=*" %%A in ('"type %SystemRoot%\System32\drivers\etc\hosts"') do (
   set var=%%A
   if NOT "!var:~0,1!" == "#" (echo !var!)
)
```